# Problema com exercicio de C

Tags: c

O exercicio pede isso : 5.  Faça um programa que leia uma sequência de números entre 1 e 20 e mostre quantas vezes cada número apareceu. A sequência de números termina com um número igual a zero.

Já tentei de tudo, não consigo fazer a ultima parte para informar quantas vezes cada numero aparece..mudei o codigo diversas vezes e continua dando crash quando digito os numeros, no momento está assim :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int digitado,contador,i,vetPrincipal[0],vetContador[0],repeticoes;

    printf("Digite um numero de 1 a 20, o ultimo sendo 0");
    scanf("%i",digitado);

    while(digitado != 0){
        if(digitado > 0 && digitado<20){
            printf("Digite um numero: \n");
            scanf("%i",digitado);
            vetPrincipal[contador] = digitado;
            //percorre o vetor e insere na posição em que foi adicionado o resultado de quantas vezes apareceu o numero
            repeticoes =1;
            for(i=0;i<contador;i++){
                if (vetPrincipal[i]==digitado){
                    repeticoes++;
                    vetContador[contador] = repeticoes;
                    contador++;
                }
                else        {
                    break;
                }

                //mostra o resultado
                for (i=0;i<20;i++){
                    printf("O numero %d foi digitado %d vezes",vetPrincipal[i],vetContador[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual o tamanho dos vetores que você está usando para armazenar os dados?

Answer (score 9):

Você está criando seus vetores com tamanho zero. Por isso, quando você faz:

```
vetPrincipal[contador] = digitado;
```

Ele tenta acessar uma região de memória que não existe. Experimente dar um tamanho positivo ao seu vetor (como o problema diz que os números que aparecerão virão de `1` a `20`, um vetor de tamanho `20` deve ser o suficiente; se não houvesse essa restrição, seria necessário fazer alocação dinâmica ou usar outra estrutura de dados). Lembre-se somente que em C os índices começam no zero, não no um (i.e. o primeiro elemento é o `0`, o segundo é o `1` e o vigésimo é `19`).

Além disso, se me lembro bem, sua forma de chamar o `scanf` está incorreta:

```
scanf("%i",digitado);
```

O parâmetro para essa função deveria ser um **ponteiro** (ou endereço) para um inteiro, e não uma variável simples. Se você quer ler algo e salvar em `digitado`, passe o endereço de `digitado` como parâmetro:

```
scanf("%i",&digitado);
```

Alguns outros pontos que merecem atenção:

- A solução que você está tentando fazer envolve salvar todos os números já digitados - o que pode ser qualquer número, então não dá pra criar um vetor estático para guardá-los todos. Tente pensar numa maneira de não ter que guardar todos os números.
- Vejo que você não iniciou suas variáveis. Ao contrário de Java (por exemplo), as variáveis não iniciadas não recebem zero por padrão. Isso significa que seu `contador` não começa com `0`, mas sim com qualquer valor que por acaso estiver na memória quando seu programa começar.
- Procure sempre manter seu código bem identado, isso ajuda muito a identificar erros que de outra forma passariam despercebidos. Aposto que você não notou que você tem um `for` dentro do outro, não? E ambos com a mesma variável `i`...

No mais, não consegui entender muito bem sua lógica. Como você está aprendendo, ajuda bastante ser generoso com os comentários: dizer o que você pretende fazer, junto com o código que faz a coisa de fato. Com o tempo, e com a experiência, você pode reduzir os comentários e fazê-los em mais alto nível, mas por enquanto eu sugiro usar e abusar deles (pra você mesmo, e pra quem for ler e interpretar o que você escreveu).

Comment: +1 Muito didático!